# How do I select package using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class chrome {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://neontv.co.nz");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//*[@class='nv-nav-freetrial-2 nv-nav-item']"))
            .click();
    Thread.sleep(200);
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//ul[@id='yui_patched_v3_11_0_2_1529643447183_22']"))
            .click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.quit();

}
```

}

I am unable to select package on next page.. I tried changing the xpath but it didnt help.. is there any other way to select this. Could any one help please

Comment: site is not accessible outside nz. please share the html code?

Comment: File is too long I will upload via drop box and send

Comment: paste a useful example into the question.. nobody knows what a "package" is, based on what you've provided so far.

Comment: @SamSam : No need to upload the full file , just share the important part of HTML which will be required to solve your issue.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MOD2e31rIDTkmH-dG1UwYc4WVnZeZ-hi   This will just need google account to signin......@corey package is type of plan you can select

Answer (score 0):

Using Action classes, I was able to resolve this

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(btnEnjoy).click().build().perform();
```